# Printing out Log style in Xcode interface builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nstextview

This really shouldn't be this hard but I'm stumped.  I just want to do something simple like write out a log type area in my app.  Here is the problem, if I use NSTextField then the message gets overwritten, and if I use NSTextView I try and lock the edit feature with "setEditable" but this seems to lock up the app.  I get too many messages and it doesn't write out everything fast enough as the threads.

Pretty much what I want to reproduce is a scrolling log which the user can see, like console and using NSLog.  What should I be using?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Writing text means there's drawing code. Drawing is expensive and can tie up your main thread, so you may want to try dedicating a thread/nsoperation to appending an outputString and setting a textView's textValue to the outputString. This way, the thread that you are now running on doesn't get tied up with the drawing code.